# Using a defined helper as an iteration for a range

Tags: kubernetes-helm

While recently writing a helm chart, I ran into an issue that I couldn't find a solution to.

Basically, I am trying to range off of a defined value (labels), but appear to be running into an issue because the defined value is a string and not a map.  I tried to convert it with `toYaml` to no avail:

```
{{- range $key, $value := ( include "myChart.selectorLabels" . | toYaml ) }}
- key: {{ $key }}
  operator: In
  values:
  - {{ $value }}
{{- end }}
```

Example error with `toYaml`:

```
COMBINED OUTPUT:
  Error: Failed to render chart: exit status 1: Error: template: myApp/templates/deployment.yaml:103:77: executing "myApp/templates/deployment.yaml" at <toYaml>: range can't iterate over |-
    app.kubernetes.io/name: myApp
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: env-myApp
    conf-sha: 0b92fad469486fedb6ad012c1b5f22c
```

Example error without `toYaml` (note lack of linebreak before first value):

```
COMBINED OUTPUT:
  Error: Failed to render chart: exit status 1: Error: template: myApp/templates/deployment.yaml:103:73: executing "myApp/templates/deployment.yaml" at <.>: range can't iterate over app.kubernetes.io/name: myApp
  app.kubernetes.io/instance: env-myApp
  conf-sha: 0b92fad469486fedb6ad012c1b5f22c
```

Expected render:

```
- key: app.kubernetes.io/name
  operator: In
  values:
  - myApp
- key: app.kubernetes.io/instance
  operator: In
  values:
  - env-myApp
- key: conf-sha
  operator: In
  values:
  - 0b92fad469486fedb6ad012c1b5f22c
```

I think there must be a more elegant solution to this in helm's templating that I am missing.

Comment: Do you mean `fromYaml` and not `toYaml` here?

Comment: @DavidMaze that worked!  It doesn't appear to be well documented though. :/ https://www.google.com/search?q=%22fromYaml%22+site%3Ahelm.sh  Thanks for the help! TL;DR - Working solution: `{{- range $key, $value := ( include "myChart.selectorLabels" . | fromYaml ) }}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Helm has two extension functions to convert between strings and complex YAML structures.  You're calling `toYaml` which takes an arbitrary object and serializes it to a YAML string.  What you actually have is the string result from `include` which happens to be parseable YAML, and you need the opposite function, `fromYaml`.

```
{{- range $key, $value := ( include "myChart.selectorLabels" . | fromYaml ) }}
{{/*-                                                 not toYaml ^^^^     */}}
```

Neither function is especially well-documented.  They are specific to Helm.  There are corresponding `toJson` and `fromJson` that work similarly.